# Display image in reactjs fetched from rest API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, components

I want to display the images of a particular product. I am fetching the images of a product and the images path is printing correctly in the console but the images does not display in the page.
Is there some other method to do it?

ProductImage.jsx

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function ProductImage({product_id}) {

  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get(`products/${product_id}/images`);
      setImages(data);
      data.map((image) => {
        console.log(image.image);
      })
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((image) => {
        return <img key={image.id} src={image} alt="some-image" />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
src={image}
```

`src` needs to be a url, currently you are passing it what looks like an object `image`

Try logging just `image` to see what key holds the url, then you can set it. For example if the image's path is in `image.image`:

```
src={image.image}
```

BTW `data.map` is the wrong method to use - if you just want to loop through the data use `data.forEach`

Comment: {id: 2, image: '/media/products/images/Screenshot_22.png', product: 2} this is what an image object looks like.

Comment: So if `src` needs to be a URL what do you think it should be set to?

Comment: image.image is not displaying anything too.

Comment: No worries I got the answer. Thank you btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
{images.map((image) => {
   return <img key={image.id} src={image.image} alt="some-image" />
})}
```

Based on your image object, I think this is the right way to do it

Comment: Tried it but nothing changed

Comment: Would you like to check out the browser html console? What's in the img src?

Comment: /media/products/images/Screenshot_22.png.
this is result of the console.log(image.image);

Comment: I got the images displayed.
<img key={image.id} src={'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+image.image} alt="some-image" />

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
src={`${URL.createObjectURL(image?.image)}`}
```

or,

```
src={`${rootUrl}${image?.image}`}
```

Here, rootUrl looks like "192.168.31.183:8000"

Comment: I did like src={'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+image.image} and this is working. Thanks for your asnwer.